# How to return a simple xml string from a form post in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I've got a simple http POST action in Spring MVC and I don't need to return a full web page. Instead I just need to return an xml string (for example)

true

But when I exec the action below my client is getting a 404

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateStuffAjaxStyle.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateStuffAjaxStyle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //..do something w/ the inputs ...

    return "<valid>true</valid>";
}
```

Is it possible to return a simple xml string like this w/out having to define a ton of bean defs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. But not by returning the String from your method, but by writing it to the `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` and changing the method signature to return `void` (this way, Spring will know that you'll handle the response yourself).

To grab the servlet response writer, simply add one extra argument of type `java.io.Writer` to your method, and Spring will provide you with the proper reference.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can do this by annotating your method return type with the `@ResponseBody` annotation like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateStuffAjaxStyle.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateStuffAjaxStyle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    //..do something w/ the inputs ...
    return "<valid>true</valid>";
}
```

Comment: What if I am wanting to return SVG XML to display in an `<img>` tag?

Comment: I don't see why this should be any different to the above. Just swap out the string above with the SVG XML you want to use.

Comment: I had to create a `HttpHeaders` object and set the `content type`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190243/can-you-set-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-image-tag-to-a-controller-method) that I made.