# Spring MVC: No conversion from text to application/xml

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to collect all the form data and send it as a XML to Controller. This XML will further be sent to back end which will take care of it.
JAXBMarshaller expects a bean to be defined for marshalling incoming xml. But I don't have one.

**Request**:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        processData: false,
                        data: collectFormData1(),
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"application/xml"
                        },
                        dataType: 'application/xml',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Success:'+data)
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('jqXHR:'+jqXHR+'\n'+'textStatus:'+'\n'+textStatus+'errorThrown:'+errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
function collectFormData1()
            {
                //$rootElement = $('<FormXMLDoxument/>');
                xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                root = xmlDoc.createElement($('form').attr('name'));
                $('form').find('div.section').each(function(index, section) {
                    sectionElement = xmlDoc.createElement($(section).attr('name'));
                    //xmlDoc.appendChild(sectionElement);
                    $(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
                        fieldElement  = xmlDoc.createElement($(field).attr('name'));
                        fieldText=xmlDoc.createTextNode($(field).val());
                        fieldElement.appendChild(fieldText);
                        sectionElement.appendChild(fieldElement);
                    });
                    root.appendChild(sectionElement);
                });
                xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
                console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));
                return xmlDoc;                  
            }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"})
        @ResponseBody public String handleSave(@RequestBody String formData)
        {

            System.out.println("comes here");
            System.out.println(formData);//prints the form xml
return "<response>Success</response>";

    }
```

Comment: In order to get help, please edit and add code for `collectFormData1()` and spring MVC config

Comment: Very likely due to missing required HttpMessageConverter that can marshall/unmarshall xml. Adding JAXB might fix it. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Sithsu I have spent whole day to setup logging for Spring but could not make it work. I am not getting Spring logs on my Tomcat console.

Comment: Spring uses JCL internally. Check http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?35531-Logging-Configuration-and-Integration, http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/ and others on configuration. Also, tomcat might be sending logs to multiple log files. Check all files in tomcat/logs/ directory.

Comment: Yeah I went through first articles. Posted logging issue as another question http://goo.gl/GznEMz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely due to missing [HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) that can marshall/unmarshall xml.

Add `spring-oxm` if you haven't already done that.

Also use `@EnableWebMvc` in your `@Configuration` component, if you are using classpath scanning.
If not, add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in configuration to enable default converters.

http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/01/rest-with-spring-contentnegotiatingview.html

**Update**

---

Try adding `produces={"application/xml"}` to `@RequestMapping`.

If its a simple xml string that needs to be returned as the response body, you could use HttpServletResponse.getWriter() as explained in [How to return a simple xml string from a form post in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859047/how-to-return-a-simple-xml-string-from-a-form-post-in-spring-mvc) or return a `ResponseEntity<String>` containing the xml.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"})
@ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<String> handleSave(@RequestBody String formData)
{

    System.out.println("comes here");
    System.out.println(formData);//prints the form xml

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("<response>Success</response>", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: So I have added `spring-oxm` jar to my class path. `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is already there in my `appname-servlet.xml`. I can't use JAXB marshal because I am converting incoming XML to some Object. I just need the xml.