# Can you set the src attribute of an HTML image tag to a controller method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, svg

I know that you can do this

```
<img src="http://some_svg_on_the_web" />
```

But what if I have a controller method annotated with `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value="getSVG")
public @ResponseBody String getSVG(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServerletResponse response) {
    String SVG = // build the SVG XML as a string

    return SVG;
}
```

Can I then say

```
<img src="/getSVG" />
```

I have tested and the controller is definitely being hit but no image is being shown on the page.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Even if the image is SVG?

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. Is your XML correctly formatted following whatever the SVG schema is?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe so, it definitely displays in browser if I open the SVG file directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is Spring is setting the default content type to `application/octet-stream` and the browser can't read your XML as that. Instead, you need to actually set the `Content-Type` header, either through the `HttpServerletResponse` or with Spring's `ResponseEntity`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="getSVG")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getSVG(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServerletResponse response) {
    String SVG = // build the SVG XML as a string
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/svg+xml"));
    ResponseEntity<String> svgEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(svg, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return svgEntity;
}
```

The fact that the you have the XML as a `String` doesn't really matter, you could've used `getBytes()` to make the content `byte[]`. You can also use the `Resource` class to have Spring get the bytes directly from a classpath or file system resource. You would parameterize `ResponseEntity` accordingly (there are a number of supported types).